# Winforms Null Reference Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, winforms, unhandled-exception

Sorry guys, I know it'll be pretty basic but I can't get to it. Please help, Thanks a lot

Winforms Null Reference Exception was unhandled - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Model.ClientModel Client = new Model.ClientModel(); // Create Instance of Model
Client.id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); // Setting fields
Client.clientName = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();// Setting fields
Client.company = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
Client.website = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
Client.emails = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
Client.phone= row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
Client.mobile = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
Client.location = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
Client.referrer = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
Client.currency = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
Client.ratePerWord = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
Client.notes = row.Cells[11].Value.ToString();

Clients.EditClient editClient = new Clients.EditClient(Client); // Passing Model to the constructor of EditClient Class

editClient.Show(); // Displaying form
```

Now the EditClient (Form Class):

```
public partial class EditClient : Form
{
   public Model.ClientModel Client;

   public EditClient(Model.ClientModel Client)
   {
      // TODO: Complete member initialization
      this.Client = Client; //Getting the Model Object passed by the previous class
      fillForm();
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   public void fillForm()
   {
      //Here I set all the model data to the fields

      textBox1.Text = Client.clientName;  //This is where the ERROR Occurs - NULLReferenceException was unhandled.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      textBox2.Text = Client.company;
      textBox3.Text = Client.website;
      textBox4.Text = Client.emails;
      textBox5.Text = Client.phone;
      textBox6.Text = Client.mobile;
      textBox7.Text = Client.location;
      textBox8.Text = Client.referrer;
      textBox9.Text = Client.currency;
      textBox10.Text = Client.ratePerWord;
      textBox11.Text = Client.notes;
   }
}
```

Can you please tell what is causing this? I've tried several ways but the same error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Place a breakpoint on the line that gives the error and hit F5. When the code stops at the breakpoint look at the value of Client.

Comment: Why you tagged Asp.net?

Comment: I've debugged, the Client object got all the values in the certain properties. the textBoxes are null. :(

Comment: Sorry for accidentally tagging asp.net.

Comment: Both the answers below are correct. Check those answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to fill your form before it is initialized, so all your textboxes are null, try this instead in your `EditClient` constructor:

```
public EditClient(Model.ClientModel Client)
{
    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    this.Client = Client; //Getting the Model Object passed by the previous class
    InitializeComponent();
    fillForm();        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call your `fillForm()` method *after* calling `InitializeComponent()`.

You are getting a Null Reference Exception because your text boxes are null - the text boxes (and other controls) are initialized in the `InitializeComponent()` method. Only after you can assign values to them.

Comment: If I use fillForm() before the InitializeComponent() the error is same and goes back to:

     'private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[11].Value.ToString());

            Model.ClientModel Client = new Model.ClientModel();
            Client.id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());'

Comment: @DanishFayaz you should call it **after** `InitializeComponent` not **before**

Comment: Thanks for your help too :) Appreciate it